# Do I really need two versions of == operator overload?

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, c++14

Do I have to provide two different versions of operator `==` overload so that it works regardless of the LHS & RHS variant of expressions. Eg.

```
Class A {

...
bool operator==(int const& L, A const& R);
bool operator==(A const& L, int const& R);
...
};
```

For usage like -

```
A a;
int x = 8;
if( a == 5 || x == a){
  ...
}
```

And why is there a need to do so? Isn't `L == R` == `R == L`?

Comment: Yes, you need to do so.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ isn't there some way to do that with single version of `==` overload? Why two different versions when `L == R` is same as `R == L`?

Comment: No! That can't be done.

Comment: "Isn't `L == R` == `R == L`"? Not necessarily. It is for you to decide.

Comment: If your property of equality is commutative, you *could* just write one and then only ever compare in that specific order.  But it would be easier on another developer that wishes to extend your class if you had both.

Comment: Maybe you can let one of version to forward the comparison to another like `bool operator==(A const& L, int const& R) { return R == L; }`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

C++ does not define any operator to be commutative or symmetric. Hence, it cannot automatically translate:

```
if( x == a){
```

to

```
if( a == x){
```

or vice versa.

If you want the compiler to be able to correctly process

```
if( x == a){
```

you have to overload the `operator==` with the type of the first object as `int` or `int const&`.

Comment: note that the word "commutative" is typically applied to operations (think addition), whereas the word "symmetric" is typically applied to relations (think equality)

Answer (score 2):

If there's an implicit conversion from `int` to `A`, you get symmetry for free.

```
class A
{
    int i_;
public:
    constexpr A(int i) noexcept : i_{i} {}

    friend constexpr bool operator==(A const& L, A const& R) noexcept
        {return L.i_ == R.i_;}
};

int
main()
{
    constexpr A a1{1};
    static_assert(a1 == 1, "");
    static_assert(1 == a1, "");
}
```

If not, or if you don't want to pay for that implicit conversion on comparison, then you have to provide it manually if desired.

This is a self-consistent language design.  If you don't want implicit conversions from `int` to `A` (or vice-versa), then you *probably* don't want to be able to implicitly imply that `A` and `int` can be equal.  But you can opt-in to such a design by writing your own heterogeneous comparisons.

Comment: note that the word "commutative" is typically applied to operations (think addition), whereas the word "symmetric" is typically applied to relations (think equality)

Comment: also, it's probably better to add mixed type overloads rather than to rely on implicit conversions, mainly because overloads generalize to class templates (no conversions during template argument deduction)

Comment: @TemplateRex: Thanks for the suggestions! I subbed in "symmetry" for "commutative" in my answer. On implicit conversions: I'm not willing to imply any value judgement for or against. Sometimes I use implicit conversions and sometimes I use explicit conversions. I find both useful.The subject of "which you should use when" is difficult and far beyond the scope of this question. I do maintain that both are useful. I'm very interested in learning about (or creating) concrete guidelines for when one should use one verses the other. I've begun work on such guidelines but it is far from complete.

Comment: I was probably too strong in my taste for explicit conversions. Do you have any draft for your guidelines on this topic that I could take a look at? FWIW, the [C++ Core Guidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Ro-conversion) currently discourage implicit conversions.

Comment: @TemplateRex:  No working draft at this time.  I'm taking note of examples where I favor implicit conversions and where I favor explicit conversions.  Not surprisingly most of my current examples of each are in `<chrono>` and my date/timezone library.  I've been mulling this over for years, and will probably continue to do so.  So a draft is not imminent (unless maybe this is my Cppcon 2017 topic?! ;-) )

Comment: Ah ok, I think I have seen some of those thoughts on SO, like only implicitly convert if there cannot be a loss of information. In any case, `constexpr` user-defined literals also provide close to the same brevity in expressions as implicit conversions, but with full type safety. Anyway, looking forward to a future talk on this!

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do this without having to write both `==` each time.

```
namespace bob {
struct equality_support {
  template<class T, class U>
  using supported =
    std::integral_constant< bool,
      std::is_base_of< equality_support, std::decay_t<T> >{}
      && decltype( (void(std::declval<T>().equals( std::declval<U>() ) ), true) ){true}
    >;

  template<class T, class U,
    class=std::enable_if_t< supported<T const&, U const&>{} >
  >
  friend bool operator==( T const& t, U const& u ) {
    return t.equals(u);
  }
  template<class T, class U,
    class=std::enable_if_t<
      !supported<T const&, U const&>{}
      && supported<U const&, T const&>{}
    >,
    class=void
  >
  friend bool operator==( T const& t, U const& u ) {
    return u.equals(t);
  }
  template<class T, class U>
  friend auto operator!=( T const& t, U const& u )
  -> decltype( !(t==u) )
  { return !(t==u); }
};
}
```

now, if I wrote that right, derive from `equality_support` then override `bool equals( int ) const` and it will work both ways.

```
struct A:
  bob::equality_support
{
  bool equals( int x ) const { return x==42; }
};
```

Test code:

```
int main() {
    A a;
    std::cout << (a==7) << (a!=7) << (a==42) << (a!=42) << '\n';
    std::cout << (a==0.0) << (a=='a') << '\n';
    // std::cout << (a == "hello") << "\n"; // does not compile
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/10705f3a29053b94).

I would pick a better namespace name than `bob`.

If you want to support `A==A`, you can do `bool equals( A const& ) const` or provide a conversion to `int`.

The run time cost of this technique is near zero, assuming modest optimization and inlining by your compiler.

What I did was exploit argument dependent lookup and SFINAE to allow inheriting from the `equality_support` to write `operator==` and `operator!=` that eventually dispatch to calling (non-virtually) an `equals` method on a type inherited from `equality_support`.

It does this in a symmetric manner, unless both sides of the `==` have `equality_support`, in which case is prefers to invoke `lhs.equals(rhs)`.  So if the `.equals` method is assymetric, you'll get asymetric results in that case.

`!=` is automatically written to invert `==`.

The example `struct A` I wrote always compares equal to `42`; this is mostly a joke.  It can do whatever it wants in the body of `equals`.

The SFINAE I wrote would have to be rewritten to reliably work in MSVC 2015.  It is only nominally a C++11 compiler; it still has large gaps in its implementation in the SFINAE area.

Comment: Why would you mock the Almighty Bob? :(

Comment: I guess `class=void` is to modify the signature of the function template? Why not use `en_if_t<..>* = 0`?

Comment: @dyp MSVC sucks?  I have had issues with SFINAE overloading using non-type template parameters.  I haven't using the stupid "add another `class=void` to distinguish" technique.  Bah, I just noticed I was using an expression in that SFINAE, so it won't work in MSVC much anyhow.  Sign.